# preventdefault() on <a> tag is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript, I am writing a accordion menu using Javascript. I succeed it. But finally I have a bug my program.

Let's assume CAPITAL letters are first level menus, small letters are second level menus.

If A has children, Show them "a b c d" when click on A.

If it hasn't just show the page is link to A.

This is the condition I want to apply.

But I am blocked somewhere. Actually, it works like

If A has children ,Show them "a b c d" when click on A. 
If it hasn't, A is not clickable link.

Here is my source code.

MyJSFile.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){
    if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
      // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
      $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
      $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");

      // open our new menu and add the open class
      $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
      $(this).addClass("open");
    }

    else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    }
  });
});
```

here is my CSS class's MyCSS.css

```
#nav {   
  padding-left:0px;
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
 }
#nav > li > a:hover, #nav > li > a.open {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #38454B;

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0.35, #212121),
    color-stop(1, #866F4A));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #212121 35%, #866F4A 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #212121 35%, #866F4A 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #212121 35%, #866F4A 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #212121 35%, #866F4A 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #212121 35%, #866F4A 100%);
}

#nav li ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #CCC;
    list-style-type: none; 
}
```

Html nav is here

```
 <nav>
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="">Accueil</a></li>

        <li><a href="Aller à la page 1">Podologie</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Aller à la page 2.1">Présentation</a></li>
            <li><a href="">*Pododiabétologie</a></li>
            <li><a href="">*Podopédiatrie</a></li>
            <li><a href="">*Podologie sportive</a></li>
            <li><a href="Aller à la page 2.3">Les conseils du podologue</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="index.php?pays=FR&page=contact">Contacts</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=web+design+icons">Lien1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=web+design+tutorials">Lien2</a></li>
            <li><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=web+design+user+interface">Lien3</a></li>
            <li><a href="http:/www.google.com/search?q=web+design">Lien4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

**EDIT by a third party:**

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3STdc/

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle ? please

Comment: Wild guess, the parent element doesn't have an UL ?

Comment: Add a `console.log` inside your `$(this).parent().has("ul")` conditional to make sure it's even getting to that block.

Comment: post the html of nav.

Answer (score 1):

`if ($(this).parent().has("ul"))` will always be `true`, since [it returns a jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/has/).

Replace it with `if ($(this).parent().has("ul").length)`

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/cUthP/

`if ($(this).siblings('ul').length)` is slightly shorter and would also work.

Comment: That's a good point, though then it should make `.preventDefault()` always work. Still needs to be fixed though. +1

Comment: thank you. i modified with ".length" now it's working.

Comment: @TilwinJoy OP has shared it, in an edit. Please reload the question.

Comment: @TilwinJoy The HTML was edited in before I posted my response. I used it in my fiddle. Check the complete edit history.